# Indirect function help in Excel/G-sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sheet 1

Source data

Sheet 2

I have sheet name in cell A1: ABCD
I have range reference in cell A2: $F:$F

Using sumifs and indirect to make the column reference dynamic for sum range dynamic, but getting an error.

How can this be accomplished?

Tried sumif and indirect function but getting an error